# How to make boostrap v5. elements full-width screen?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using .net framework for making my project. I want to make my element's width screen size. But almost I tried all ways on StackOverflow solutions. I can not reach to solution.

I am using Bootstrap v5.2.3.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Give this div your desired background color -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    ... your content here ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or: (HTML code)

@*Container
Container Fluid

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                ...
                <div class="full-width-div">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>*@
```

Or: ( CSS code)

```
.full-width-div {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
    }
```

How can I do[image]

I want to make all my elements (such as: "p" I want to make its background colour full screen.) width full-screen size. How can I fix it?

Comment: `container-fluid` should use 100%. But the default skin of a blank project has `<div class="container body-content">` in `_Layout.cshtml`. Maybe test with that html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how container looks like. Therefore, I have 2 layouts in my project. One is with container and the other in full width

This is part section of default layout with container

```
 <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
```

This is another layout with 100% width

```
 <div class="parent" style="padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
```

You can switch the view for different View by inserting this

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
     Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_LayoutTrans.cshtml";
}
```

Comment: I am so happy now. It works. But I could not understand.  what do you mean ? "You can switch the view for different View by inserting this."

Comment: it means you can have 2 layouts in u project. When u create a view, u can choose between the 2 by adding the command above on the top part of the view